# Let $g=(v,e)$ where $v=z100$ and $E=\{(a,b)\mid \gcd(a,b)=1\}$. Determine whether $G$ is bipartite graph and whether G is connected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is confusing, I can't determine through equations, all I know is from graph shown, I need some explanation, been searching all over youtube on how to solve this, but none.

z100 = {(0),(2),(3),,...(99)} |v|=100 whereas |E| = let b=32, a=2 a not eq b 2 not eq 32 , E ={(2),(32)} this is based on my own understanding, correct me if there's mistake

then to determine, stuck there

Comment: Do you know what $z$ is?

Comment: z100 = {(0),(2),(3),,...(99)} |v|=100 whereas |E| = let b=32, a=2 a not eq b 2 not eq 32 , E ={(2),(32)} this is based on my own understanding, correct me if there's mistake, i\m so bad at this subject :(

Answer (score 1):

You have a graph (V,E) such that the vertices are represented by $V = \{0 ,2,3, \dots , 99\}$  and the edges $E$ are those linking relative prime integers in $V$.

First notice that $\gcd(a,0) = a$ for every $a$ hence $0$ is an isolated vertex.

Also notice that $97$ is a prime number, hence $\gcd(a,97) =1$ for $0<a<97$ and it is not difficult to see that $\gcd(97,98) =\gcd(97,99) =1$. Therefore every vertex other than $0$ is connected to $97$ and  the graph is neither connected nor bipartite.

Comment: if i change E={(a,b)|a not equal b and a is a prime factor of b} ?

Comment: How do you define a prime factor of $0$?

Comment: any whole number times zero is equal to zero, so infinite?

Comment: That makes sense?

Comment: getting dizzy ;"( still don't get it

Comment: I'd recommend you draw the graph.